# PyBBIO Analog Input: Failure to Load ADC File

Tags: beagleboneblack

While running the [PyBBIO](https://github.com/alexanderhiam/PyBBIO) examples phant_test.py and analog_test.py I received the following error (I believe 'could' is a typo meant to be 'could not'):

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "analog_test.py", line 47, in <module>
      run(setup, loop)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyBBIO-0.9-py2.7-linux-armv7l.egg/bbio/bbio.py", line 63, in run
      loop()
    File "analog_test.py", line 37, in loop
      val1 = analogRead(pot1)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyBBIO-0.9-py2.7-linux-armv7l.egg/bbio/platform/beaglebone/bone_3_8/adc.py", line 46, in analogRead
      raise Exception('*Could load overlay for adc_pin: %s' % adc_pin)
    Exception: *Could load overlay for adc_pin: ['/sys/devices/ocp.2/PyBBIO-AIN0.*/AIN0', 'PyBBIO-AIN0', 'P9.39']
```

I have tried restarting the BeagleBone (rev A6 running Angstrom with a 3.8 kernel, with no capes connected) to clear the `/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.7/slots` file, but that did not work. It seems PyBBIO is accessing the slots file and adding overlays because the slots file looks like this after the example program runs:

```
     0: 54:PF--- 
     1: 55:PF--- 
     2: 56:PF--- 
     3: 57:PF--- 
     4: ff:P-O-L Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,PyBBIO-ADC
     5: ff:P-O-L Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,PyBBIO-AIN0
```

Since there were some changes being made to the slots file I checked what files the `analog_read(adc_pin)` function in the [adc.py](https://github.com/alexanderhiam/PyBBIO/blob/master/bbio/platform/beaglebone/bone_3_8/adc.py) file of PyBBIO was retrieving. With some print statements I figured out the root problem was that the `/sys/devices/ocp.2/PyBBIO-AIN0.*/AIN0` file, which apparently stores the analog read values, does not exist. The `glob.glob` function returns a null array, and `ls /sys/devices/ocp.2/PyBBIO-AIN0.10/` shows `modalias  power  subsystem  uevent` as the only contents. Is there something wrong in the overlay file? Or could there be another program or problem that is preventing the BeagleBone from writing the `AIN0` file that PyBBIO is trying to read? The python code seems to be logically correct, but the overlay is working incorrectly or being blocked in some way.